# Checkbox is no more checkable after enable from component - Angular 2/4/5

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

Let me explain the scenario I want to achieve first!

I have a select box and assume it has values like i1, i2, i3, i4, i5.
Besides the select box, I have a checkbox.

The checkbox will be disabled initially.
Now, When I select i2 or i3, I want to enable the checkbox.

and if it other than i2 and i3, need to disable and uncheck the checkbox.

Here is my DOM code:

```
<mat-select placeholder="item" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" [formControl]="selectedItem[ix]" required
            (ngModelChange)="allowCheck(ix, checkBox)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of allItems()" [value]="item">
        {{ item }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>

<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkMe" #checkBox>
</mat-checkbox>
```

Here is my TS code:

```
allItems() {
    return [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5];
}

allowCheck(ix: number, checkBox: MdCheckBox) {
            checkBox.disabled   = true;
            if(this.selectedItem === 'i2' || this.selectedItem === 'i3') {
                checkBox.disabled   = false;
                checkBox.ripple.disabled   = false;
            }
            else {
                checkBox.disabled   = true;
                checkBox.checked    = false;
            }
        }
```

this solution enabling the checkbox, but I am not able to check it. Can someone please suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: You'll need to provide some code from your view template in order for people to be able to help.

Comment: Hey There, I have updated my question with some code. Please have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the answer, just to save others from spending a day.

Initially (onload) make the checkbox disable.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.disabledCheck = true;
}
allowCheck(ix: number, checkBox) {
    checkBox.disabled   = true;
    if(this.selectedItem === 'i2' || this.selectedItem === 'i3'){
        this.disabledCheck = false;
    }
    else {
        this.disabledCheck = true;
        this.checkMe = false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-select placeholder="item" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" [formControl]="selectedItem[ix]" required
            (ngModelChange)="allowCheck(ix, checkBox)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of allItems()" [value]="item">
        {{ item }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>

<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkMe" #checkBox [disabled]="disabledCheck">
</mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass your strings as string.

This is an array of empty vars of type 'any'. They never return true comparing them by '=== some string'.

```
allItems() {
    return [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5];
}
```

Try it this way

```
allItems() {
    return ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5'];
}
```

or alternatively

```
const i1='i1';
const i2='i2';
const i3='i3';
const i4='i4';
const i5='i5';

allItems() {
    return [i1, i2, i3, i4, i5];
}
```